# How to turn off proximity sensor when returning back from child activity to parent activity

Tags: android, proximity

I have taken *proximity sensor* in my child activity which works fine but when I am returning back to parent activity The *Proximity sensor* still remains turn on. I had unregistered proximity sensor in `onPause` and `onDestroy` of my child activity but still remains turn on. I have taken proximity sensor to turn off screen when near to face just like call app which turns on *Proximity sensor* and after ending call it returns back to childActivity but the *Proximity sensor* still remains on.

My **ChildActivity** is given below :

```
Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBar actionBar;

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mProximity;
PowerManager pm;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
private static final String MYLOCK=ProximitySensorActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_proximity_sensor);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Proximity Sensor");
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.left);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);


}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float distance = event.values[0];

    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, MYLOCK);

        if (distance<1 && wakeLock!=null){
            if (!wakeLock.isHeld()){
                wakeLock.acquire();
            }
        }else if (wakeLock!=null){
            if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                wakeLock.release();
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }

        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id=item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You register it in `onResume();`
`onResume();` is called when the `Activity` if brought to front, in case of returning from another activity it is called as well.
To prevent this, create some flag , and set it to true in `onPause`, when you unregister receiver. And in `onResume()` check for that flag.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with `wakeLock` here in `onPause()` and/or `onDestroy()`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (wakeLock!= null) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (wakeLock!= null) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Note that I have replaced `wakeLock.isHeld()` with `wakeLock!= null`, for some reason `WakeLock.isHeld()` keeps returning false. Even after `WakeLock.acquire()` is called.

You only need to release wakelock in `onPause()`.

Comment: This gives me Exception : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.app2.apptwo/com.app2.apptwo.ProximitySensorActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked ProximitySensorActivity

Comment: Works for me, I made an entire project and Activity just to see what was wrong here. Are you sure you did everything correctly? Sounds like there is an `Activity LifeCycle` issue.